# long long constant number in swift

Tags: swift

I'm looking Swift alias for Objective-C constant `long long int` and `float` numbers.

That is, how can this : `1000LL` and `.1f` be converted into Swift code?

No information found here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `as`-casting when you need to specify literal types in Swift.

`1000LL` -> `1000 as Int64`

`.1f` -> `0.1 as Float`

Comment: Also: `Int64(1000)` or `let i: Int64 = 1000` – anything which allows the compiler to infer the type.